# How to receive all body from GET request in bunches of 1 minute each

Tags: go

I need my application to get all body from series of POST request made to it within 1 minute from say 12:00 to 12:01 into one array/sruct (so I can process it all immediately after 1 minute). Then again this should restart to get for the next one minute and so on.

This is in golang I'm trying to build. Receiving data in JSON.

```
func (m *StreamsDAO) Insert(stream model.Stream) error {
    err := db.C(COLLECTION).Insert(&stream)
    return err
}
```

Instead of directly inserting into db (`err := db.C(COLLECTION).Insert(&stream)`) I need all data for 1 minute process it then insert, again get all for next 1 minute and so on.

Comment: Is this one single http GET or a series of GETs? What is the format of the http  body? JSON? You need to post more details. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Updated. I'm not getting how to proceed in this case as I'm new in golang. Till now I was just inserting the data in db after every post call. But now I've different requirement.

Comment: You can run code at regular intervals using a [Ticker](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker). Simply store the records in an appropriate data structure (slice, linked list, channel, etc.) during the sleep phase. This site isn't a code writing service, so the question is too broad. We'll be happy to help you with any concrete problems you encounter.

Comment: What is special about one minute intervals? Why not process data immediately, or in the background?

Comment: My application is listening at 10m rpm. I need to store this data and also upon request I need to process this data and respond with chunks of 1 mins of processed data. This will create some latency because of processing time on this huge data. So, now I'm processing the data at consumption time and then storing. Doing so saves my network bandwidth while sending data to DB and also decreases latency when data requested.